# AWS ECS task fails to start becasue daemon can't create Logstream

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 2 versions of a service that run in the same cluster. I'm using the awslogs driver

The v2 logs works fine however the v1 task fails to start because it can't create a log stream.

The setup is identical between services except for the container being used.

The log group exists and the role has permissions to create a "logstream" and can "putevents" as this is pretty much the same setup for the v2 in a different group.

```
CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://logs.eu-west-1-v1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup logs.eu-west-1
```

I've setup a new service and tried to spin it up again but it failed so I thought that this was to do with the container setup.

On the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html) it recommends adding this to the environment variables

```
ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS   '["json-file","awslogs"]'
```

After adding this, it still failed.  I've been searching for a while on this and would appreciate any help or preferably guidance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the endpoint should just be "https://logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com". There is no `-v1` endpoint listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/cwl_region.html Can you post the entire container definition in your question?

Comment: Thank you so much!  the issue was in the region setting.  It was modifying this in our build pipeline.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, the log configuration in my task definition is as below -  "awslogs-group": "/ecs/new-task",
"awslogs-region": "ap-south-1",
"awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs" ; could you please suggest if anything needs to be changed here?